# Always running a line/Running 2 lines at once in C

Tags: c, background-process

Im hoping to make a clicker game from C. I already have the clicking mechanics down and im pretty confident i can do everything else but I can seem to find any articles or help regarding having a running line in the background. For example I have a line of code that allows whenever I click a key i get +1 money, but like most clicker games I want a auto klicker to be running every second or so. So i can just be normally clicking while at the same time theirs a function or line of code that adds +5 money every so often. Ive made my own (delay) code so thats not an issue, its just running a line in the background. Heres what I have so far...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{

    int menu;
    char ch;
    int klicks;
    int klickses;
    klicks=0;

    void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
while (goal > clock());
}

   printf("Welcome to Key Klicker! This game is a idle game where you slowly gain more and more klicks over time.\n The game is never ending but their are milestones to reach.\n A menu will open up to help navigate through the game.\n");
 do{
   printf(" 1: Clicking\n 2: Shop\n 3: Exit\n\n");
   scanf("%d", &menu);
    if(menu == 1)
    {
        klickses=0;
        {
   char ch;
   printf("Klick as fast as you can! (ESC to exit)\n");
   while (1) { //define infinite loop for taking keys
      if (kbhit) {
         ch = getch(); // Get typed character into ch
         klicks=klicks+1;
         klickses=klickses+1;
         if ((int)ch == 27) //when esc button is pressed, then it will comeout from loop
         break;
         printf("+1\n");
      }

   }


    }
    printf("You have a total of %d klicks!\n", klicks);
    printf("You earned %d klicks that session!\n\n", klickses);
    }
    else if(menu == 2)
    {
        printf("work in progress\n");
    }
    else if (menu == 3)
    {
        printf("exit work in progress\n");
    }

}while (1);


}
```

Comment: You should create a thread.! What is you target platform?

Comment: The if (kbhit) works fine. And im just hoping to have a constant running line adding 5 to a integer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got it to work! Basically instead of having a auto adder every so seconds I decided to make a stopwatch that starts at the beginning and ends when I go out of the auto clicker. I then minus the end time from the start time and just calculate the auto clicks from their!

I also think with a new variable I just learned called time_t I could make an if statement that if a certain time is passed it would add 5 but anyhoo im not going to vere onto another path. This communities super helpful keep it going!